# A question on an isosceles obtuse angled triangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Given an isosceles triangle with equal sides of length $b$ and base angle $A$ $(<π/4)$. $O$ and $I$ are the circumcenter and incenter of the triangle respectively. Then true or false
$$OI= \left|\frac{b \cos(3A/2)}{2\sin(A) \cos (A/2)}\right|.$$

I have found out the values of the inradius and circumradius to be $b \sin(2 A)/2(1+\cos A)$ and $b/2 \sin(A)$ respectively and also that the isosceles triangle is obtuse angled. I also know that in an isosceles triangle the circumcenter and incenter lie on the same straight line. But I have no idea how to find $OI$. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are right.

Let in $\Delta ABC$ we have: $AC=CB=b$, $\measuredangle A=\alpha$,

$D$ be midpoint of $AB$ and $E$ be a midpoint of $BC$.

Thus, $CD=b\sin\alpha$, $CO=\frac{b}{2\sin\alpha}$, $ID=b\cos\alpha\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and
$$OI=|CD-CO-ID|=\left|b\sin\alpha-\frac{b}{2\sin\alpha}-b\cos\alpha\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}\right|=$$
$$=\frac{b}{2\sin\alpha\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}}\left|2\sin^2\alpha\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}-\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}-2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\right|=$$
$$=\frac{b}{2\sin\alpha\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}}\left|\cos2\alpha\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}+\sin2\alpha\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\right|=$$
$$=\frac{b\left|\cos\frac{3\alpha}{2}\right|}{2\sin\alpha\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}},$$
which you got.

Comment: By ID you mean inradius right?

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar Yes, of course.

Comment: hahah....ok thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

this distance is given by $$d=R^2-2Rr$$ this is the formula of Euler

Comment: Any short and sweet proof for this?

Comment: see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxJy9V0gPZ0 i hope this will help you

Comment: I'm having problem simplifying the expression. Can you please help me by writing down the simplification?

Comment: which expression do you mean?

Comment: d=R^2-2Rr. I have reached the denominator part....having some trouble

Comment: here is a better proof for you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry